# libQxt widgets not showing in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, mingw, qt-creator, libqxt

I have installed libQxt 0.6.2 successfully, it creates a `C:\QXT` folder. My Qt 4.7.4 is configured for MinGW. When I run:

```
%QTDIR%\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\bin\designer.exe
```

The QXT widgets are shown in the toolbox.

But when I run:

```
%QTDIR%\QtCreator\bin\qtcreator.exe
```

it does not show the QXT widgets. It's like the plugins are not installed in Qt Creator.

How do I get the QXT widgets to show in Qt Creator?

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator is built with Visual C++ 2008 and only works with the plugins compiled with that same compiler.

So you have to build libQxt with Visual C++ too or recompile QtCreator with MinGW.